# Python import fails with sublime text but program runs through console

Tags: python, import, build, sublimetext3

Importing a module that i just downloaded to my python program in sublime text fails. When using 'command +B' it just tells me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'epo_ops'".
I just installed the module through pip install and when running it from the console it works absolutely fine.
Why is that?

Comment: Sublime is probably using a different python interpreter than the console

Comment: thanks for the reply @DroidX86. i am pretty new to this. is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how sublime+python works. Maybe you can run `python --version` in `cmd+B` and see?

Comment: By default, Sublime executes `python` to run Python scripts, and it's not unheard of for this to be a different version of Python than you expect depending on your platform. I would suggest running a script like `import sys; print(sys.version)` from Sublime and the terminal and double check that it's running the correct version, as @DroidX86 mentioned above.